# Как вытащить из базы MySQL случайные n количество записей (строк)?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть задача вытащить 10 случайных записей из таблицы. Насколько я знаю это можно сделать через `LIMIT $some_num, 10`. Но это не совсем то, что нужно. Потому, что если записей скажем 15, то отсутствует вероятность того что 1 и 15 строки таблицы будут в одной выборке. А это уже какой никакой, но порядок. Нужна абсолютная случайность. Как решить эту задачу?
Спасибо.

P.S.: Очень рассчитываю на то, что это можно сделать стандартными средствами `MySQL`.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Выборка произвольных записей в MySQL (HabraHabr)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/54176/)
2. [Как выбрать случайную запись из базы MySQL без использования первичного ключа и order by rand() (HabraHabr)](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/1269/)

Comment: В предложенных вами решениях преобладает только LIMIT, но как я писал в вопросе это не вариант. Пока только остается вариант комбинации ORDER BY LIMIT и php: 

ORDER BY() $rand LIMIT 10.

Comment: На большом количестве данных запросы с ORDER BY RAND() будут тормозить, возможно баг пофиксили, надо гуглить.

Comment: http://plutov.by/post/order_by_rand_performance
http://glebov-gin.blogspot.ru/2011/03/order-by-rand-mysql.html

Comment: Я имел ввиду сделать тот же RAND() тольк на php поэтому я указал $rand, а не RAND(). Я вот если честно не совсем понимаю почему ORDER BY RAND() вообще работает. Я понимаю когда по имени столбца или его позиции, но чтобы по числу с плав. точкой. Не могли бы вы объяснить буду признателен.

Comment: @z_coder если вы из php в $rand подставите значение, то рандома не будет. функция RAND() в выражении order by будет вычислена для каждой возвращаемой записи, практически сортировка идет по дополнительному столбцу, в котором значения получаются с помощью rand(). отсюда и тормоза. но в php рандомизировать еще хуже.